# Solve the integral $\int \frac{\sinh\left(x\right)-2}{2\sinh\left(x\right)+\cosh\left(x\right)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand that I do not write any steps. But please help me in solving this prolemy.
$$\int \frac{\sinh\left(x\right)-2}{2\sinh\left(x\right)+\cosh\left(x\right)} dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sinh x-2}{2\sinh x+\cosh x}=\frac{2\sinh x-4}{4\sinh x+2\cosh x}=\frac{e^{2x}-4e^x-1}{3e^{2x}-1}$$
hence by replacing $x$ with $\log t$ we just need to integrate:
$$\frac{t^2-4t-1}{t(3t^2-1)}$$
and this is not difficult to achieve through partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: you are right, now fixed.